# Mean of Randomvariable

Tags: random, variable

I want to calculate Mean[x+y].

`x = NormalDistribution[]`
`y = NormalDistribution[]`
`Mean[x + y]`

but output is not 0.
Mathematica's out put is following.

Mean[2 NormalDistribution[0, 1]]

How to get 0 ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Use `2 Mean[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]` instead of `Mean[2 NormalDistribution[0, 1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
g = TransformedDistribution[x + y, 
  {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
   y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]

Mean[g]
```

(* 0 *)

Comment: Thank you very much!
You are great.